# Paypal eCheck Response

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I've been searching for the eCheck type payment response from Paypal but I wasn't able to find some answers. I have a project which is developed about 1 year ago by another developer but there is a problem with eCheck payments. With instant payment there is no problem, whenever customer pays with credit card Paypal sends a response to our server to URL xyz.com/pay/paypal?token=123456 etc. however when we got eCheck and when eCheck is cleared we are supposed to get same response to same URL but we  don't get any response. I don't have much knowledge about paypal that is why I'm asking. The question is, is paypal response sent to our specified URL whenever it gets payment from customer (it also sends mail to shop owner as payment is done) or shop owner (paypal owner) must accept manually the payment and clear it out in paypal account and only then the response will be sent to our specified URL? I hope I was able to explain my problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

eChecks do not require the merchant to manually accept them.

I assume you are using [Instant Payment Notifications(IPN)](https://www.paypal.com/ipn). If so, you can find a [list of IPN variables](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_html_IPNandPDTVariables) on PayPal's doc site.

If you do a quick CTRL+F for 'echeck', you'll find that 'payment_type' is set to 'echeck' when echeck is the method of payment.

- 'payment_status' will also be set to 'Pending'
- 'pending_reason' will be set to 'echeck'

At this point, your website should indicate that the payment is still pending, and awaiting completion. You should not provide the product to your customer until you receive an IPN indicating that the payment has completed.

---

### **IPN when echeck is first sent:**

mc_gross=15.00&protection_eligibility=Ineligible&address_status=unconfirmed&payer_id=GNT5WLV6WKLYW&tax=0.00&address_street=1+Main+St&payment_date=16%3A44%3A18+Feb+27%2C+2012+PST&payment_status=Pending&charset=windows-1252&address_zip=95131&first_name=Buyer&address_country_code=US&address_name=Test+Store&notify_version=3.4&custom=&payer_status=verified&business=Merchant%40paypal.com&address_country=United+States&address_city=San+Jose&quantity=1&verify_sign=AgAlUZhjLO7LZONEcdS31FYzErz-AHeUkv3Zu0vaWWcnojCUP0Vd0xFU&payer_email=Buyer%40paypal.com&txn_id=8GE50731F5580773J&payment_type=echeck&payer_business_name=Test+Store&last_name=test&address_state=CA&receiver_email=Merchant%40paypal.com&shipping_discount=0.00&insurance_amount=0.00&receiver_id=GNWYP52JJQDNC&pending_reason=echeck&txn_type=web_accept&item_name=test&discount=0.00&mc_currency=USD&item_number=&residence_country=US&test_ipn=1&shipping_method=Ground&handling_amount=0.00&transaction_subject=test&payment_gross=15.00&shipping=14.00&ipn_track_id=c554e1fc8b9c

---

I would post the IPN that is sent once the echeck is sent, but I don't have one handy, and the one associated with the above payment won't show until 01 MAR 2012.

Comment: If you provide me the IPN on March 1st I would be really glad. Thank you.

Comment: I'm still waiting for my echeck to clear, and the receipt of the "echeck cleared" IPN message. I will update my answer when it clears.

Answer (score 0):

For info of others, I have a similar situation and it appears to me that IF one has multiple wesbiets using sam paypal a/c the final echeck clearing IPN is sent to the ONE notification URL specified in paypal rather than the dynamic URL sent by the original paypal request.

this may be your problem - check the notification url setup in paypal.